# Creating multiple self-referencing foreign keys to the same table

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have a class like this:

```
[Table("Tree")]
public class Tree 
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int TreeId { get; set; }

    public int? TreeOneId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("TreeOneId")]
    public virtual Tree TreeOne { get; set; }

    public int? TreeTwoId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("TreeTwoId")]
    public virtual Tree TreeTwo { get; set; }

}
```

When I create the database from this class definition, I get the error:

> Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types 'Tree' and 'Tree'. The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API or data annotations.

If I remove one of the properties, and create a class definition like this:

```
[Table("Tree")]
public class Tree 
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int TreeId { get; set; }

    public int? TreeOneId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("TreeOneId")]
    public virtual Tree TreeOne { get; set; }

    //public int? TreeTwoId { get; set; }

    //[ForeignKey("TreeTwoId")]
    //public virtual Tree TreeTwo { get; set; }

}
```

It does create the correct tables.  How can I get by this error?  I've tried specifying the column order, adding a unique index.  I can work around this by using a List TreeOne, and it will create the corresponding linking table, but I would rather not have to use that solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic problem here is, that SQL will not allow you to precisely define a binary tree.

In your approach it would be possible for a tree item to have multiple parents, since nothing prevents LeftId and RightId to point to the same reference or to have another tree item pointing to the same sub-tree.

We need a defined end-point for the navigation properties on Left/Right. This is the key to a solution: define a separate inverse navigation property for left/right child items and account for the possibility to have multiple parents.

With that in mind, lets set up the model for entity framework. Note that I replaced `Tree` by `TreeItem`, since its one entry per tree-node and used `Left`, `Right` instead of your property names out of lazyness.

```
public class TreeItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int? LeftId { get; set; }
    public int? RightId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("LeftId")]
    [InverseProperty("Parent1")]
    public virtual TreeItem Left { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("RightId")]
    [InverseProperty("Parent2")]
    public virtual TreeItem Right { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Left")]
    public virtual ICollection<TreeItem> Parent1 { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("Right")]
    public virtual ICollection<TreeItem> Parent2 { get; set; }
}
```

Also note: I tested only in EF6, so no guarantee to work with EF5

Comment: Awesome solution.  I saw many examples that showed how to use this relation between two classes, but not contained within the same class.